# Verb for "piece together clues"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Is there a verb that more or less means "***to piece together clues***"?  I'm looking for something like "*detectivize*," which, unfortunately, isn't a word.

The closest I came up with is "*investigate*," but this is far from my intended meaning.

Comment: To 'infer' something is to come to a conclusion based on a set of information.

Comment: This might require a neologism.

Comment: We need context. Otherwise people will keep throwing words at the wall at random. Which is not helping anyone, least of all yourself. We try to provide clear answers to clear questions. And we clearly fail at that when you get ten answers within a couple hours, some of which can't even make their mind up and are really, in turn, ten separate answers in their own right.

Comment: There is a defined term for this concept. A valid 'single-word request' question. See my answer. Voting to re-open.

Comment: I've checked the FAQ and this type of questions appears to be the first recommended point to ask on this site. Some of the answers are excellent quality and the question has 7 upvotes and two favs but the moderators STILL think it's "not good enough".

Comment: @RegDwighт On the comment, I checked the OP's phrase '*piece together*' the usual, preferred and recommended GR way, online Thesaurus: "Main Entry: reconstruct" (http://thesaurus.com/browse/piece+together) -- seems the question has enough substance.

Comment: @Kris: you make it sound like it should be closed as general reference instead. Also, in case you haven't noticed, the OP already has accepted an answer and it is does not so much as mention *reconstruct*. (Instead it mentions *ratiocinate*, whatever that is.) Look at the upvote situation, too. You are fighting a losing battle, I am afraid. This question is a train wreck right now, in no small part thanks to the multicollider.

Comment: @RegDwighт I'd have happily accepted it as a GR closure, though it's not a straight GR question. If it's been wrecked, it's because of some or mostly guess-work answers and not because of the asker's fault. Perhaps, OP's bad luck.

Comment: @SF. I humbly direct you to the canonical meta post [Against single word requests](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/against-single-word-requests). Do take a minute to apply the criteria outlined there to the question at hand. Do also note that the votes here have been heavily skewed by the multicollider. (And the very fact that this got onto the multicollider in the first place is, by design, a rather strong sign of it being mindless bikeshedding.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The canonical work of detective reasoning, [The Complete Sherlock Holmes](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=complete%20sherlock%20holmes&btnG=) uses:

- *reason* 71 times (although not necessarily all as a verb)
- *deduce* 19 times
- *solve* — 16
- *puzzle* — 12 (*puzzle out* — 6)
- *unravel* — 5
- *infer* — 4
- *sleuth* — 1
- *decipher* — 1
- *ratiocinate* — 0

Comment: Since ratiocinate has 0 mentions, what brought you to introduce that word?

Comment: @JeffFerland: Elementary! 3nafish has picked out words that he thought might be a good fit (perhaps with a thesaurus?), and then looked for those words in Doyle's work. You couldn't deduce that? ;^) By the way, I'm surprised that _observe_ (39 times) was left of this list. Clearly, Holmes felt that [_observing_](http://bigthink.com/artful-choice/dont-just-see-observe-what-sherlock-holmes-can-teach-us-about-mindful-decisions) (as opposed to just _seeing_) was an important element of his success.

Comment: It is just that **none** of these can be applied exclusively and specifically as the verb required in OP's context.

Comment: @Kris: Perhaps not, but where did the O.P. specify "exclusively and specifically"? (I see "[more or less](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=more+or+less)".) Depending on the context, a couple of these might work just fine – more or less. I thought *ratiocinate* was a particularly good candidate.

Answer (score 13):

I might go with something like "[deduce](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deduce)".

Answer (score 9):

You might try ***sleuth***:

> [***sleuth***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sleuth?rdfrom=Sleuth) *(verb)*  :  *To act as a detective; to try to discover who committed a crime.*

Comment: As in supersleuth :p .

Answer (score 7):

Consider *[ferret out](http://www.websters-dictionary-online.net/definitions/ferret_out)*, meaning to “search and discover through persistent investigation”.

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with these related terms.  Perhaps they'll fit favorably with your context.

- *conclude*
- *infer*
- *amalgamate*
- *fuse*
- *determine*
- *decide*
- *judge*
- *deduce*

Comment: I was just thinking of amalgamate.

Answer (score 4):

***Reconstruct***

> [Crime reconstruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crime_reconstruction) or crime scene reconstruction is the forensic science discipline in which one gains "explicit knowledge of the series of events that surround the commission of a crime using deductive and inductive reasoning, physical evidence, scientific methods, and their interrelationships.
>
> Crime scene **reconstruction** has been described as **putting together a jigsaw puzzle** but doing so without access to the box top; ...
> <sub>(Wikipedia)</sub>

[emphasis mine]

> [reconstruction](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/reconstruction) (Oxford Dictionaries)
> (1 b) [*count noun*] an impression, model, or re-enactment of a past event formed from the available evidence:
> *a reconstruction of the accident would be staged to try to discover the cause of the tragedy*

Synonym to *[piece together](http://thesaurus.com/browse/piece+together)* thesaurus.com (2.)

> *Main Entry: **reconstruct***

Answer (score 3):

You could use [*solve*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/solve):

> 1. To find a solution to.
> 2. To work out a correct solution to (a problem).

One might also [*decipher*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/deciphered) clues:

> 1. To read or interpret (ambiguous, obscure, or illegible matter).
> 2. To convert from a code or cipher to plain text; decode.

Answer (score 3):

Though I think @Jim's *sleuth* is nice, in some circumstances, **Analyze** would be best.

Comment: +1 *Analyze* would technically be the correct word. However, people in the field do not use it simply because that word already has a different meaning.

Answer (score 2):

If you're [not exactly a prescriptive grammarian](http://www.shakesville.com/2011/07/denouement.html) and can live with using [denouement](http://www.wordnik.com/words/denouement) as a verb as [Melissa McEwan does here](http://www.shakesville.com/2011/07/in-which-i-utterly-refuse-to-credit-as.html):

> "And then there's this: If 99% of the man who professed cluelessness
>   in defense of their misogyny were actually just clueless, 99% of the
>   "garsh, misogyny?!" conversations would **dénouement** with a grateful
>   thank you for feminist enlightenment, instead of snarling flounces
>   punctuated with accusations of man-hating and grievances about
>   unwelcoming tones."

then that word might just fit what you're looking for. Of course, denouements are after the climax of story.

Answer (score 2):

*Decode* or *decipher* could be the words I think you want.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your answer would be more helpful if both explained why those words would be appropriate and linked to sources.